# Create Project Java Web without maven and Ide

Tags: java

**I am trying to create an application for creating java web projects in a personalized, automated way, without maven, without IDE, but so far I have not seen anything on the internet that would suit me.

Could someone guide me or tell me how I can do it?**

Comment: What do you mean with "Java web project"? A JSP page, a WAR or EAR file or a complete web server? Anyway I don't think that you will find someone explaining you the hundred of commands/steps you need to do so if Maven/Gradle only requires one file and ~4 commands.

Comment: Very difficult to realize and also not recommended.

Comment: This question is really broad, can you maybe be more specific?

Comment: That sounds like you want to build a large house, only using a shovel, and no trucks please. One can only wonder: why?

Comment: Do you want to build something like start.spring.io?

Comment: It's a personal project, so I just wanted an orientation. If java has some class that does this, a framework or command line does that. It has an application that allows you to create this custom project. At first J2EE.

Comment: @LucianoFerreira Why not use Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I consider your question differently that you want to create an application which when run can automatically create web projects !! If that is correct you need to write set of programs which would make files necessary for your web project like generate java files, Jsp files, XML, properties etc depending on complexity of your web projects, also if customized with parameters it can make different kinds of projects. Then you will need to make war file which is going to be the final deploy-able component with these files. This is all that you would do manually through IDE and maven would be the jar files you would need if any. Let me know if you need any more help.

Please accept and like if you appreciate my gesture to help with my ideas n experience.